# Unable to install pandas using Python3.8

Tags: python, pandas, shell

When I try to install `pandas` on a Linux machine, I run into the below issue. Please let me know what dependency am I missing here or if there is any other issue.

The same command worked fine when I installed with `Python3`

Python version - `Python3.8`

```
# python3.8 -m pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/f0/f99700ef327e51d291efdf4a6de29e685c4d198cbf8531541fc84d169e0e/pandas-1.3.5.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 188, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 345, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 196, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 359, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 305, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 214, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/source.py", line 70, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    reqs = self.req.pep517_backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 70, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._call_hook('get_requires_for_build_wheel', {
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 162, in _call_hook
    raise BackendUnavailable
pip._vendor.pep517.wrappers.BackendUnavailable
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 21.3.1 is available.
```

When executed as  `python3.8 -m pip install --no-use-pep517 pandas`, observing below issue -

```
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xt3n6dn0/pandas/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xt3n6dn0/pandas/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-xt3n6dn0/pandas/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 35, in <module>
        from setuptools import windows_support
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
        import ctypes
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: rather belongs to [superuser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: try `sudo yum install python38-devel`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
python3.8 -m pip install --no-use-pep517 pandas
```

Maybe you should also upgrade `pip` and `setuptools` before:

```
python3.8 -m pip install -U pip setuptools
```

Comment: i was able to install the pandas after upgrading the `pip` and `setuptools` but when i checked by importing pandas, i see this issue now - `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:124: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
  warnings.warn(msg)`

Comment: What is your distro?

Comment: CentOS Linux release

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe

`pip cache purge` to clean all cached packages,

also you can try to install after the update of pip - `pip install --upgrade pip`.

If that does not help, try to make a virtual environment with your python3.8 and try to install packages inside that venv.